# Deactivate GPU and use IGP

Tags: linux, laptop, graphics-card, gpu, igp

I am having some trouble with my Sony Vaio SVE1511W1e laptop. It has an ATI Radeon and the i5 has an IGP (i5 2450m).

I don't often use my GPU, and the IGP would be just enough for most usage I do. Therefore, in order to improve the battery life, I wish to deactivate the GPU and use only the IGP.

The problem is that my BIOS doesnt allow me to do so. But I believe it is possible to deactivate the GPU 'programatically'. I'm running Debian Wheezy on the 3.2.0.4 AMD64 kernel.

The first problem I'm running into is that when I run lspci, my IGP doesnt show up. Could this be because im lacking a kernel module? (I chose a targeted installation).

What are the solutions to deactivating a GPU and using an IGP on a Linux System such as debian?

Comment: Hi squelos - you state "I don't often use my GPU, and the IGP would be just for". You may want to add to the sentence what the "just for" is that you are talking about. Just for clarity ;)

Comment: Do you have anything in `/sys/kernel/debug/vga_switcharoo` ?

Comment: No my debug folder in /sys/kernel is empty.

Comment: so you must compile your own customize kernel for your specific purpose

Answer (score 1):

### vga_switcheroo

As suggested, one way is to use **vga_switcheroo**. If you don't have it as a module try to install **linux-firmware-nonfree** and modprobe it with **debugfs** as well.

With **vga_switcheroo** loaded, as root, verify the state of the discrete GPU:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

and then, try to turn it off:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

If this method doesn't work you can try to use **acpi_call** to turn off your discrete video card.

### acpi_call

This package is not in the debian wheezy repository, so you've to compile it by yourself

Try to follow [this blog post](http://garyservin.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/disabling-discrete-gpu-in-debian-gnulinux-wheezy/) and use the script **test_off** to try all the methods available and see if it works.

Have a look also to the [ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hybrid_graphics), most of the information will works also for Debian.